# Can't read custom config section after using ILMerge

Tags: .net, app-config, nlog, ilmerge

Subject:
I create console application (documents parser) and use NLog for logging processing events.
After build i use ILMerge tool for merging all DLLs to one executable file (it needed for more confortable using result tool)

If i use external NLog.config xml-file for loggers configuration - it's work good (before and after merging all dll-s and exe to single file)

So, problem:
But if i trying to use "nlog" section in docsloader.exe.config file - it's work only without merging by IL (if all dll and exe files in separately mode).
If i firstly merge result to single file and run docsloader.exe i see:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for nlog: Could not load file or
 assembly 'NLog' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. (C:\d\projects\_\out\docsloader.exe.Config line 5)
---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'NLog' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

docsloader.exe.config (first 20 strings)

```
<configSections>
      <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog" />
</configSections>  

<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd">
  <targets>
        <target name="console" type="Console" layout="${date:format=HH\:mm\:ss}|${level}| ${message}" />
        <target name="file"  type="File" fileName="${basedir}/docsloader.log" layout="${date}|${level}| ${message}" />
    </targets>
    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="console" />
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="file" />
    </rules>
  </nlog>

<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6"/>
</startup>

....
```

ILMerge command:

```
C:\d\projects\_\ILMerge\ILMerge.exe /out:"C:\d\projects\_\_\out\docsloader.exe" "C:\d\projects\_\_\bin\Release\docsloader.exe" "C:\d\projects\_\_\bin\Release\*.dll" /target:exe /targetplatform:v4,C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319 /lib:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0" /wildcards

echo Coping docsloader.exe.config...
cp C:\d\projects\_\_\bin\Release\docsloader.exe.config C:\d\projects\_\_\out\docsloader.exe.config
```

PS: If i remove -section and create NLog.config - it's work correctly.
Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error comes from the type reference `NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog` which refers to `NLog` dll (after the comma), which no longer exists as it's now merged.

You can replace it by `NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, docsloader` and it'll probably work.

Comment: Great, thank You! PS: My mistake was and that i tried to use project name after the comma (instead NLog), but i't was incorrect, because build script in VS set another name for output .exe-file (ontoloader). Your answer is workable.